# Move XML once they're processed in Feeds

Tags: 7, feeds

Currently, I'm using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) & [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) for importing XMLs into my Drupal 7.x site. As per the requirement, it's working perfectly fine expect the moving feature.

What I need to do is to move the XML files once they are processed, is there any hook or something which can be helpful for me on this? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got similar requirement some time ago, I've got a [thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2201977#comment-10754456) where this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/option_delete_after_import-2201977-3.patch) works very well with Feeds directory fetcher [7.x-2.0-beta5](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_fetcher_directory).

```
diff --git a/feeds_fetcher_directory.module b/feeds_fetcher_directory.module
index 24b0137..c37295e 100644
--- a/feeds_fetcher_directory.module
+++ b/feeds_fetcher_directory.module
@@ -29,3 +29,50 @@ function feeds_fetcher_directory_ctools_plugin_api($owner, $api) {
   }
 }

+/**
+ * Implements hook_feeds_after_import().
+ *
+ * @param FeedsSource $source
+ */
+function feeds_fetcher_directory_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {
+  // We alter import only if fetcher is 'feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher'.
+  if (get_class($source->importer->fetcher) != 'feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher' || !$source->importer->fetcher->config['after_processed']) {
+    return;
+  }
+
+  foreach ($source->config['feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher']['feed_files_fetched'] as $file_path => $value) {
+    // Check if file exist, becouse we could already delete it.
+    if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
+      continue;
+    }
+
+    // Determine whatever this is managed or unmanaged file.
+    $file_unmanaged = FALSE;
+    if (!($file = reset(file_load_multiple(array(), array(
+      'uri' => $file_path
+    ))))) {
+      $file_unmanaged = TRUE;
+    }
+    ;
+
+    // Delete or move file, according to config.
+    switch ($source->importer->fetcher->config['after_processed']) {
+      case FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_DELETE:
+        $file_unmanaged ? file_unmanaged_delete($file_path) : file_delete($file, TRUE);
+
+        break;
+      case FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_MOVE:
+        // Move file, and save folder substructure.
+        $new_file_name = $source->importer->fetcher->config['move_to_folder'] . '/' . substr($file_path, strlen(($source->importer->fetcher->config['directory'])));
+        file_prepare_directory(dirname($new_file_name), FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
+
+        if ($file_unmanaged) {
+          file_unmanaged_move($file_path, $new_file_name, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
+        } else {
+          $file_moved = file_move($file, $new_file_name, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
+        }
+
+        break;
+    }
+  }
+}
diff --git a/feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher.inc b/feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher.inc
index b48c878..537bb06 100644
--- a/feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher.inc
+++ b/feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher.inc
@@ -5,6 +5,9 @@
  *
  * Provides the Feeds Directory Fetcher to feeds.
  */
+define('FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_NO_ACTION', 0);
+define('FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_DELETE', 1);
+define('FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_MOVE', 2);

 /**
  * Fetches a file from a specified directory.
@@ -79,7 +82,7 @@ class feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher extends FeedsFileFetcher {
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => t('Directory'),
       '#description' => t('Specify a URI to scan for feed data, e.g. private://files-to-scan.'),
-      '#default_value' => isset($source_config['source']) ? $source_config['source'] : '',
+      '#default_value' => (isset($source_config['source']) && !empty($source_config['source'])) ? $source_config['source'] : $this->config['directory'],
       '#required' => TRUE,
     );
     $form['reset'] = array(
@@ -116,10 +119,16 @@ class feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher extends FeedsFileFetcher {
    * Override parent::configDefaults().
    */
   public function configDefaults() {
+    $schemes = $this->getSchemes();
+    $scheme = in_array('private', $schemes) ? 'private' : 'public';
+
     return array(
       'recursive' => TRUE,
+      'directory' => $scheme . '://feeds',
       'filemask' => '/\.txt$/',
       'updated_files' => FALSE,
+      'after_processed' => FALSE,
+      'move_to_folder' => ''
     );
   }

@@ -128,6 +137,16 @@ class feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher extends FeedsFileFetcher {
    */
   public function configForm(&$form_state) {
     $form = array();
+    $form['directory'] = array(
+      '#type' => 'textfield',
+      '#title' => t('Upload directory'),
+      '#description' => t('Directory to search for files. Prefix the path with a scheme. Available schemes: @schemes.', array('@schemes' => implode(', ', $this->getSchemes()))),
+      '#default_value' => $this->config['directory'],
+      '#states' => array(
+        'visible' => array(':input[name="direct"]' => array('checked' => FALSE)),
+        'required' => array(':input[name="direct"]' => array('checked' => FALSE)),
+      ),
+    );
     $form['filemask'] = array(
       '#type' =>'textfield',
       '#title' => t('File mask'),
@@ -139,6 +158,29 @@ class feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher extends FeedsFileFetcher {
       '#title' => t('Re-fetch files that are modified'),
       '#default_value' => $this->config['updated_files'],
     );
+    $form['after_processed'] = array(
+      '#type' => 'radios',
+      '#title' => t('After process'),
+      '#options' => array(
+        FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_NO_ACTION => t('No action'),
+        FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_DELETE => t('Delete files'),
+        FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_MOVE => t('Move to folder')
+      ),
+      '#default_value' => $this->config['after_processed']
+    );
+    $form['move_to_folder'] = array(
+      '#type' => 'textfield',
+      '#title' => t('Move to folder'),
+      '#description' => t('Specify a folder, to which files will be moved after being processed. Available schemes: public, private.'),
+      '#default_value' => $this->config['move_to_folder'],
+      '#states' => array(
+        'visible' => array(
+          ':input[name="after_processed"]' => array(
+            'value' => FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_MOVE
+          )
+        )
+      )
+    );
     $form['recursive'] = array(
       '#type' =>'checkbox',
       '#title' => t('Recursively scan directory'),
@@ -147,4 +189,50 @@ class feeds_fetcher_directory_fetcher extends FeedsFileFetcher {
     );
     return $form;
   }
+
+  /**
+   * Overrides parent::configFormValidate().
+   *
+   * Ensure that the chosen directory is accessible.
+   */
+  public function configFormValidate(&$values) {
+
+    $values['directory'] = trim($values['directory']);
+
+    // Validate the URI scheme of the upload directory.
+    $scheme = file_uri_scheme($values['directory']);
+    if (!$scheme || !in_array($scheme, $this->getSchemes())) {
+      form_set_error('directory', t('Please enter a valid scheme into the directory location.'));
+
+      // Return here so that attempts to create the directory below don't
+      // throw warnings.
+      return;
+    }
+
+    // Ensure that the upload directory exists.
+    if (!file_prepare_directory($values['directory'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS)) {
+      form_set_error('directory', t('The chosen directory does not exist and attempts to create it failed.'));
+    }
+
+    // Validate move_to_folder if after_processed set to "move".
+    if ($values['after_processed'] == FEEDS_FETCHER_DIRECTORY_FETCHER_MOVE) {
+      $values['move_to_folder'] = trim($values['move_to_folder']);
+
+      // Validate the URI scheme of the move_to_folder.
+      $move_to_sheme = file_uri_scheme($values['move_to_folder']);
+      if (!$move_to_sheme || !in_array($move_to_sheme, $this->getSchemes())) {
+        form_set_error('move_to_folder', t('Please enter a valid scheme into the move to folder.'));
+
+        // Return here so that attempts to create the folder below don't
+        // throw warnings.
+        return;
+      }
+
+      // Ensure that the move_to_folder exists.
+      if (!file_prepare_directory($values['move_to_folder'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS)) {
+        form_set_error('move_to_folder', t('The chosen directory does not exist and attempts to create it failed.'));
+      }
+    }
+  }
+
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_feeds_after_import to move xml after successful import.

```
/**
 * Invoked after a feed source has been imported.
 *
 * @param FeedsSource $source
 *  FeedsSource object that describes the source that has been imported.
 */
function hook_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {
  // See geotaxonomy module's implementation for an example.

  // We can also check for an exception in this hook. The exception should not
  // be thrown here, Feeds will handle it.
  if (isset($source->exception)) {
    watchdog('mymodule', 'An exception occurred during importing!', array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    mymodule_panic_reaction($source);
  }else {

        // You can write here you own code to move xml.

   }
 }
```